# How to remove the forwards slash that AngularJS ng-src adds to a url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an application that uses the following code

```
        <li ng-repeat="video in videos.feed.entry">
        <div>
            <h4>{{video.title.$t}}</h4>
            <img ng-src="{{video.media$group.media$thumbnail[2].url}}">
        </div>
    </li>
```

however the end result adds a forwards slash to the src attribute and it looks like this

```
<img ng-src="/http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4x-elJk6hWY/2.jpg" src="/http://i.ytimg.com/vi/4x-elJk6hWY/2.jpg">
```

note the forwards slash before the http. Is there any way to remove that or am I ding something wrong?

Comment: Why do you have a '/' before the "http.." value for `ng-src`?

Comment: awkward naming convention..

Comment: Can you setup a plunker/jsfiddle with reproduced behavior?

Comment: Turned out to be the PHP template

Answer (score 0):

It was the PHP template and not AngularJs that was causing the trouble.